# Array Object Acceptable Globally, but Not in Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an array, which is populated with objects. The objects have two values, one containing a list item, and another containing a float (price). I'm trying to push the list into a DOM element, but the variable is globally undefined.

This code outputs the second array item to the console:

```
$('#coll-price-filter').change(function() {
    var newList = [];
    $('#coll-product-list li').each(function(idx, li) {
        pprice = $(li).find('.coll-prod-price').html().trim().substring(1)
        pprice = parseInt(pprice);
        newList[idx] = {
            value: $(li).wrap('<div></div>').parent().html(),
            price: pprice
        }
        newList.sort(function(a, b){  
            a = a.price, b = b.price;
            return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
        });
    });
    console.log(newList[1].value);
});
```

However this does not

```
$('#coll-price-filter').change(function() {
    var newList = [];
    $('#coll-product-list li').each(function(idx, li) {
        pprice = $(li).find('.coll-prod-price').html().trim().substring(1)
        pprice = parseInt(pprice);
        newList[idx] = {
            value: $(li).wrap('<div></div>').parent().html(),
            price: pprice
        }
        newList.sort(function(a, b){  
            a = a.price, b = b.price;
            return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
        });
    });

    i = newList.length;
    while (i > 0) {
        console.log(newList[i].listItem);
        i--;
    }
});
```

So it appears that the while loop is breaking the accessibility of the `newList[]` object. I've tried it a few ways, and it works if I'm inside the `.each()` iterator. But I need to access it outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Array indices are `0` based, this:

```
    i = newList.length;
```

should be this:

```
    i = newList.length - 1;
```

Otherwise the starting index is out of bounds, so `newList[i]` will be `undefined`, and accessing a property on `undefined` is a *TypeError*.

Once you correct that, you probably want to access a property defined on the object, like `.value` or `.price`, otherwise it will log `undefined` for each iteration.

Comment: +1 more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements).

Comment: +1 for excellent answer. I guess I should have known that array.length doesn't count from 0 as the index does. Grey job, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this:

```
i = newList.length;
while (i > 0) {
    console.log(newList[i].listItem);
    i--;
}
```

Be this?

```
i = newList.length-1; // start on the last index, not length
while (i > 0) {
    console.log(newList[i].value); // value, like in your top example
    i--;
}
```